# Webpack - exporting directory and importing it via path

Tags: javascript, webpack

So I was trying to export a directory with webpack and came up with this script that imports recursively all the files that I need:

```
// lib1
const req = require.context('./', true, /^(?!.*test.js)^(?!.*Spec.js)^(?!.*__mocks__.*\.js)((.*\.(js\.*))[^.]*$)/)

const modules = {}

req.keys().forEach(key => {
    modules[key] = req(key)
})

export default modules
```

That works fine, I have all modules available to me on subsequent bundles of webpack but it's not exactly what I wanted.

What I really need is a way to export those modules in a way that I can import them using paths instead of grabbing this module object and accessing services via it.

Note:

Apps have `^lib` as external module.

webpack@4.1.1

```
// ex1 what I need:
import theme from 'lib1/services/theme'

// ex2 what I have:
import lib1 from 'lib1'
const theme = lib1.services.theme
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Which version of web pack you are using? If you're using webpack 2 and above, you can define aliases for your modules in the config file. Alternatively, if there are already `export` statements in all the files, you can simply include them in entry array.

Comment: webpack@4.1.1, just update the question.

Yes - I tried that, but modules are not included on the library bundle if they're not imported, right?So only putting it on `resolve.alias` didn't do it

Comment: @Terry - yep - they all have exports